# Swift: Showing action buttons on right swipe

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Instead of the default right-to-left direction I want the swiping to go from left-to-right and show action buttons on the left side of the UITableViewCell like this:

[image]

My code so far:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var myAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Action 1", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //block that runs when 'My Custom Action' button is tapped
    })

    myAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [myAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}
```

I know about https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell but I want to code this in swift. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to code this in swift just put Objective c files which you want from MGSwipeTableCell (Git) and put in your project just create one Bridging-Header.h file  and import third party class there than you get it anywhere from your project

Comment: see this link https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: Thanks, importing the class is no problem. But how do I create left buttons in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like in the demo app? I am new to iOS developement & swift.

Comment: you can create right to left swipe button but i also don't know left to right swipe buttons in cell

Comment: i suggest you only one thing that now you have to do R&D in your Git link B'coz it's a tableview cell's default functionality you want change from left to right